# Run vba module with specify of username

Tags: vba, excel

is it possible to run excel module when workbook opened by certain user?
The idea is very simple - refreshing all data source when excel workbook opened by certain user, save and close. Another way it just opens.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is probably not the answer you want to see, but why don't you try it first. And then, come to this board with a specific question. Ideally, you could paste some code and / or error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how "secure" this is, but it worked for me.  Note that you need to put this in the "ThisWorkbook" Object (not a Module):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If Environ$("Username") = "bWayne" Then
    MsgBox ("Hi Bruce")
   ' Do whatever
End If
End Sub
```

Save as `.xlsm` and when you open it, if the username is `bWayne`, the message box will show...otherwise, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Also it is possible to check Excel user's name by using

```
If Application.UserName = “bWayne” Then
…
End If
```

in Workbook_Open() procedure.